# Laravel Eloquent sorting a group by element

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

**Here is my query:**

```
return App\AftermarketParts::where('alt', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
        ->orderBy('alt',"$direction")
        ->with('aftermarket_parts_type')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('aftermarket_parts_type_id');
```

**Here is my data set:**

```
(16) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:alt:(...)
  created_at:(...)
  deleted_at:(...)
  id:(...)
  image:(...)
  image_height:(...)
  image_width:(...)
  link:(...)
  tires_and_rims_type:Object
    created_at:(...)
    deleted_at:(...)
    description:(...)
    id:(...)
    name:(...)
    updated_at:(...)
1:{…}
2:{…}
```

I am trying to sort the results by **name** of course this does not work.

```
return App\AftermarketParts::where('alt', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
            ->orderBy('alt',"$direction")
            ->orderBy('name',"$name_direction")
            ->with('aftermarket_parts_type')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('aftermarket_parts_type_id');
```

I have also tried:

```
return DB::table('aftermarket_parts')
    ->join('aftermarket_parts_categories','aftermarket_parts_categories.id','=','aftermarket_parts.aftermarket_parts_type_id')
    ->select(DB::raw(
        'aftermarket_parts.id,
        aftermarket_parts.link,
        aftermarket_parts.image,
        aftermarket_parts.webpage_screen_shot,
        aftermarket_parts.alt,
        aftermarket_parts.image_width,
        aftermarket_parts.image_height,
        aftermarket_parts.aftermarket_parts_type_id,
        aftermarket_parts.deleted_at,
        aftermarket_parts.created_at,
        aftermarket_parts.updated_at'))
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->orderBy('aftermarket_parts.alt', "$direction")
    ->orderBy('name', "$groupDirection")
    ->get();
```

**Returns DataSet:**

```
data:Array(80)
  0:
    aftermarket_parts_type_id:(...)
    alt:(...)
    created_at:(...)
    deleted_at:(...)
    id:(...)
    image:(...)
    image_height:(...)
    image_width:(...)
    link:(...)
    updated_at:(...)
    webpage_screen_shot:(...)
```

Even though its returns the orders correctly it destroys the array of objects in the format I need them in. I wonder if there is a way to do this via eloquent call or should I just use a php sort array? Ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last previous solution reverses the order of the array this one uses a bubble sort to sort the array.

```
function bubbleSort($Array) {
    $lastPos = count($Array);
    for($lastPos -1; $lastPos >= 1; $lastPos--) {
        for($i = 1; $i <= $lastPos -1; $i++) {
            if($Array[$i][0]->aftermarket_parts_type->name > $Array[$i+1][0]->aftermarket_parts_type->name) {
                $temp = $Array[$i];
                $Array[$i] = $Array[$i+1];
                $Array[$i+1] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return $Array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I could think of is to reverse the array order without using eloquent or sql. Its simple and it works.

```
$AftermarketParts = App\AftermarketParts::where([
            ['alt', 'LIKE', "%$search%"]
        ])
        ->orderBy('alt',"$direction")
        ->with('aftermarket_parts_type')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('aftermarket_parts_type_id');

    $temp = [];
    $j = 0;
    for ($i=count($AftermarketParts); $i > 0; $i--) {
        $temp[$j] = $AftermarketParts[$i];
        $j++;
    }
    return $temp;
```